# GTK installation on Mac doesn't seem to be working

Tags: terminal, install

I have been trying to get started on GTK for Mac. I followed the [installation steps](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/macos/) and ran the [hello-world program](https://www.gtk.org/docs/getting-started/hello-world/). I keep getting this error with gcc, though. Running

```sh
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk4) -o hello-world-gtk hello-world-gtk.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk4)
```

returns the following errors:

```
Package gtk4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk4' found
Package gtk4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk4' found
hello-world-gtk.c:1:10: fatal error: 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I found a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098862/how-to-install-gtk-on-osx-for-use-with-g-gcc-compiler) here, but the user says they already have gcc/g++ working. I don't.

Any ideas? I ran the installation script included in the installation steps and all I get is an error.

Comment: Have you tried adding the folder containing `gtk4.pc` to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable, as recommended in the error message?

Comment: @jaume how do i find which folder `gtk4.pc` has been installed to?

Comment: Try `find / -name gtk4.pc -type f` (this command searches the whole drive so it may need a while to finish).

Answer (score 0):

In Macos environment all brew packages are installing to `/usr/local/Cellar/` directory. You can find `gtk4.pc` file in here. Just use this command:

```
$ find /usr/local/Cellar/ -name gtk4.pc -type f
gtk4/4.10.1/lib/pkgconfig/gtk4.p
```

This is the full folder, you just add that folder to `.profile` file: `/usr/local/Cellar/gtk4/4.10.1/lib/pkgconfig`

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/gtk4/4.10.1/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Don't forget to activate this settings:

```
$ source ~/.profile
$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/usr/local/Cellar/gtk4/4.10.1/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig
$ pkg-config --modversion gtk4
4.10.1
```

Rock'n roll...

Comment: This won’t work on M1 Macs, it also will fail as soon as gtk4 gets updated. Isn‘t there a way to avoid these issues?

Comment: Also, not sure the OP used Homebrew.

Comment: I don't have M1 mac. You must set after gtk4 updated yourself. Of course there are options. For example you can create a bash file which finds correct pkgconfig paths and set environment `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable.

Comment: Can‘t you just use the stable paths Homebrew provides (see `$(brew --prefix)/lib/pkgconfig`)? And rely on `brew --prefix` for the installation directory of Homebrew?

Comment: @nohillside this is a good suggestion but libffi isn't exist in this path: `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` Because of that this isn't working unfortunatelly.

Comment: `libffi` is not part of gtk4 anyway.

Comment: But when I compile gtk4 app in rust it is required.

Comment: I understand this. How does your answer find `libffi` while using the version-independent path doesn't?

Comment: In first I disabled homebrew version update feature. I manually update packages. Then I only use latest version of every package. I'm deleting older packages. And after every update I find pkginfo folder paths with my answer and set them from `~/.profile` file.